# Проблема с подключением библиотеки brain.js

Tags: javascript

Написал нейросеть на JavaScript (должна определять рисунки), однако возникла проблема при подключении самой библиотеки brain.js. В консоли браузера выдает: "Загрузка  по адресу «file:///brain.js» не удалась." Ссылка рабочая, проверил отдельно вставив ее в адресную строку браузера.
Прошу помочь в решении данной проблемы, заранее всем спасибо :)
Код прилагается ниже:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>НС</title>

 <script src="//unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>

 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  #canv {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;
   margin: auto;
   background-color: white;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <canvas id="canv" style="display: block;">Ваш браузер устарел, обновитесь.</canvas>

 <script>
  function DCanvas(el)
  {
   const ctx = el.getContext('2d');
   const pixel = 20;

   let is_mouse_down = false;

   canv.width = 500;
   canv.height = 500;

   this.drawLine = function(x1, y1, x2, y2, color = 'gray') {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
   }

   this.drawCell = function(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
    ctx.fill();
   }

   this.clear = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
   }

   this.drawGrid = function() {
    const w = canv.width;
    const h = canv.height;
    const p = w / pixel;

    const xStep = w / p;
    const yStep = h / p;

    for( let x = 0; x < w; x += xStep )
    {
     this.drawLine(x, 0, x, h);
    }

    for( let y = 0; y < h; y += yStep )
    {
     this.drawLine(0, y, w, y);
    }
   }

   this.calculate = function(draw = false) {
    const w = canv.width;
    const h = canv.height;
    const p = w / pixel;

    const xStep = w / p;
    const yStep = h / p;

    const vector = [];
    let __draw = [];

    for( let x = 0; x < w; x += xStep )
    {
     for( let y = 0; y < h; y += yStep )
     {
      const data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, xStep, yStep);

      let nonEmptyPixelsCount = 0;
      for( i = 0; i < data.data.length; i += 10 )
      {
       const isEmpty = data.data[i] === 0;

       if( !isEmpty )
       {
        nonEmptyPixelsCount += 1;
       }
      }

      if( nonEmptyPixelsCount > 1 && draw )
      {
       __draw.push([x, y, xStep, yStep]);
      }

      vector.push(nonEmptyPixelsCount > 1 ? 1 : 0);
     }
    }

    if( draw )
    {
     this.clear();
     this.drawGrid();

     for( _d in __draw )
     {
      this.drawCell( __draw[_d][0], __draw[_d][1], __draw[_d][2], __draw[_d][3] );
     }
    }

    return vector;
   }

   el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    is_mouse_down = true;
    ctx.beginPath();
   })

   el.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    is_mouse_down = false;
   })

   el.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if( is_mouse_down )
    {
     ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
     ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
     ctx.lineWidth = pixel;

     ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
     ctx.stroke();

     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, pixel / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
     ctx.fill();

     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    }
   })
  }

  let vector = [];
  let net = null;
  let train_data = [];

  const d = new DCanvas(document.getElementById('canv'));

  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   if( e.key.toLowerCase() == 'c' )
   {
    d.clear();
   }

   if( e.key.toLowerCase() == 'v' )
   {
    vector = d.calculate(true);
    
    //train
    if( confirm('Positive?') )
    {
     train_data.push({
      input: vector,
      output: {positive: 1}
     });
    } else
    {
     train_data.push({
      input: vector,
      output: {negative: 1}
     });
    }
   }

   if( e.key.toLowerCase() == 'b' )
   {
    net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();
    net.train(train_data, {log: true});

    const result = brain.likely(d.calculate(), net);
    alert(result);
   }
  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения:

- Добавить протокол в ссылку `<script src="http://unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>`;
- Скачать `brain.js` в папку с проектом и указать к нему путь.

Когда открываешь файл локально, он не подставляет протокол поэтому у тебя и не подключается библиотека